# Are the signs of evil possessions on a person given in Vedas, Puranas and Itihasas?

Tags: vedas, puranas, itihasa, evil, ghosts

By Vedas I mean all 4 vedas, all their 4 parts and all Vedangas. By Puranas I only mean Mahapuranas. Itihasa means Ramayana, Mahabharata and the Shaiva Itihasa

Evil possessions can mean ghosts or bhoot, pret, pishach, chudail, dayan, masaan, dakini or any other evil being.

Comment: Hi. Good to see you back.

Comment: There is no reliable sign as the dark forces can act. However from their end results will always be directed into a common goal, so you can tell from that.

Comment: Basically, they have to be possessing for a reason, so they have to break from the act eventually to achieve it.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Thanks! Good to see you're still here:) Signs of possession are definitely given in Tantras and other secret books like Pret Manjari and Ravan Samhita... But I was wondering if any of this is given in non-Tantric sacred scriptures?

Comment: Atharva Veda Samhita